# How to include array into Input Stream using Android Studio?

Tags: android

I'm creating an android application which display country names with country image in a list view. The flow of my application is when you click the name of the  country it display its flag in a gif format to another activity. My problem now is I cannot include an array where I stored the gif into Input Stream.

My ListView code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar mToolbar;
    ListView mListView;

    String[] countryNames = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
    int[] countryFlags = {
            R.drawable.a,
            R.drawable.b,
            R.drawable.c,
            R.drawable.d};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mToolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, countryNames, countryFlags);
        mListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                mIntent.putExtra("countryName", countryNames[i]);
                mIntent.putExtra("countryFlag", countryFlags[i]);
                startActivity(mIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is my code where the country name clicked it shows the flag:

```
    public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GifDecoderView gifDecoderView;
    Toolbar mToolbar;
    ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);

        gifDecoderView = (GifDecoderView) findViewById(R.id.gif_decoder_view);



    }

    private void playGifByDecoderView() {
        Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (mBundle != null) {
            mToolbar.setTitle(mBundle.getString("countryName"));

            InputStream stream = null;
            try {
                stream= getString(mBundle.getInt("countryFlag"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            gifDecoderView.playGif(stream);
        }


    }
}
```

Ps. Don't mind the letters. I just change it with letters because I do trial and error. Sorry about my english. I hope you understand. Big help. Thanks

Comment: Where is the problem arises ? Is there any exception you are getting?

Comment: Could you add expected output and actual output?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to place your GIF not in the drawable folder, but in the `assets` folder. You can create a `InputStream` afterwards like this:

```
final InputStream in = getAssets().open("a.gif");
gifDecoderView.playGif(in);
```

Don't forget to handle the `IOException` properly.

Comment: Yes , that code works but I want to open a gif where it stored in my int array. please see my updated post. thanks

Comment: It's a bad idea to place animated gifs into the `drawable` folder, since they are transformed into a `BitmapDrawable`, which are not animated. -> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: Okay thanks. but can you give an idea how can I display those gif that stored in array ?

Comment: Since the animation is removed during compile time / resource merge you can simply use a regular `ImageView` to show the flags.